# [Converting Activity code to fragment]Dynamically adding images to LinearLayout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-fragmentactivity

I Have already done this in activity and I will provide part of that code as well. Basically I have a linear layout inside HorizontalScroll View and I want to add imageViews to it dynamically. The activity code for this is below and it works perfectly fine all I want is to have exact same functionality for 1 of my fragments as well. XML for the code is given below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context="com.example.scrolls_tabs.OneFragment"
android:background="@drawable/wooden_back">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and code for this that works perfectly in activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wooden_back);

    // Bitmap bdrawable = new Bitmap(this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/wood_back", "id", getPackageName()));
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int imgHeight = (int) (screenHeight* 0.30);
    int imgWidth = (int) (screenWidth* 0.25);







    for (int j=1; j<10; j++)
    {
        final int b1=j;
        create_img1("drawable/a"+j, b1, imgHeight, imgWidth);
        ImageView drag = (ImageView)findViewById(b1);
        dragAndDropImage(drag, "drawable/c"+j);
    }

    ImageView imgh=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear);
    imgh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
            localBundle.putInt("Item #1", item1);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #2", item2);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #3", item3);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #4", item4);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #5", item5);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #6", item6);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #7", item7);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #8", item8);
            localBundle.putInt("Item #9", item9);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),test_activity.class);
            i.putExtras(localBundle);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

}





void create_img1(String ss, int ID, int H, int W)
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgLayout1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(340, 340);
    parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    parms.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);

    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ss, "id", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setId(ID);

    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = H;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = W;
}
```

This is basically me looking for a solution where I get to do the same thing in fragments that I have already done in activity. I'm very new to android so anything helpful is appreciated.

Current Fragment code which is not working.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    fa = super.getActivity();
    ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


    int imgHeight = 50;
    int imgWidth = 50;

    for (int j=1; j<10; j++)
    {
        final int b1=j;
        create_img1("drawable/a"+j, b1, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    }




    return ll;
}

void create_img1(String ss, int ID, int H, int W)
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.imgLayout1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(340, 340);
    parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    parms.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);

    //int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ss, "id", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setId(ID);

    //imageView.getLayoutParams().height = H;
    //imageView.getLayoutParams().width = W;
}
```

}

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: SO is not "convert this code into fragment" service ... *Current Fragment code which is not working.* define not working

Answer (score 0):

you should add img view to linear layout like below

```
 void create_img1(String ss, int ID, int H, int W)
      {
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgLayout1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(340, 340);
parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
parms.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ss, "id", getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);

imageView.setId(ID);

imageView.getLayoutParams().height = H;
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = W;

 **linearLayout.addView(imageView);**
     }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing while trying to access the layout property in fragment ??

Comment: By seeing your log i suggest to use relative layout instead of linear layout programmatically like this `RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.imgLayout1);` or use  LinearLayout in xml instead of RelativeLayout